# different results from the for loop and the list comprehension

Tags: python, list

```
animals = ['lion' ,'tiger', 'lepord', 'cheetah', 'cat']

find = []

for name in animals:

    if name == 'lion':

        find.append(name)

print (find)

find = [find.append(name) for name in animals if name=='lion']

print (find)
```

I ran the above snippet I got the different results. 
The for loop output is `['lion']`
whereas
the list comprehension is `['none']`.

It seems to me that the for loop and the list comprehension should produce the same result. But it did not. Please help me to find why.

Comment: For starters, you're trying to `append` to a `find` which shouldn't even exist yet because it's only going to be assigned when the list comprehension has finished…

Comment: `append` doesn't return the appended list, it appends, but returns `None`.

Comment: You reassigned `find` to the list-comprehension. Don't do that, print `find`, and *voila*!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `None` comes from the list method `append` which returns `None`.

Rather than calling `append` as in:

```
[find.append(name) for name in animals if name=='lion']
```

Write:

```
[name for name in animals if name=='lion']
```

Comment: Or `filter(lambda name: name == 'lion', animals)`

Comment: @cricket_007 Only when the condition is a single function is filter preferable over the list comprehension: `[x for x in L if f(x)]` => `filter(f, L)`.

Comment: Right, which in this case, yes

Comment: when filter is used, how to print the output? print(filter(f, L) is not working.

Comment: In Python 3, `filter` returns iterator. You need to wrap it in a `list()`: `list(filter(lambda name: name == 'lion', animals))` before printing.